# How can I expand my YouTube Reporting API Rate Limits?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am using the following endpoints

- `https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs`
- `https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs/{job_id}/reports`

From the [YouTube Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest) in order to get Video Reporting data for many of my organizations customers.

At this point, our business has scaled beyond the rate limits provided for the Reporting API. What can we do to have these rate limits increased?

We have filled out [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en) to attempt to escalate, however we have not received a response. The form does mention to reach out to our YouTube Partner Manager for rates on this particular API, however we do not have a point of contact so we are unable to do that.

Comment: First off that is the form for the  YouTube data api.  Im not sure if works for YouTube analytics.  if it does it can take a while to hear back weeks.   You may not even hear back you may just get an increase and not hear anything.     Second if thats not the one for YouTube analytics no i dont know of one for Youtube analytics i have never heard of anyone applying for an extension.